# Chronos Cluster with High Availability

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere

I have three server A,B,C on each machine I'm running Chronos, ZooKeeper, mesos-master, mesos-slave.

Chronos contact mesos-master using ZooKeeper url hence it automatically picks leading master even if some node is down. I'm having high availability here.

Even Chronos run in cluster mode so accessing any of the Chronos I see same list of jobs and everything works fine.

Problem I have here is, Chronos is accessible with any of the three URLs

- `http://server_node_1:4400`
- `http://server_node_2:4400`
- `http://server_node_3:4400`

I have another application which schedules jobs in Chronos using Rest API. Which URL my application has to talk to in order in run in high availabiity mode?

Let's say my application talks to `http://server_node_1:4400` for scheduling the job, if Chronos on node `server_node_1` is down I'm not able to schedule the Job.

My application needs to talk to single URL in order to schedule job in Chronos. Even if some Chronos node is down, I should be able to schedule the job. Do I need to have some kind of load balancer between my application and Chronos cluster to pick running chronos node for job scheduling? How can I achieve high availability in my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HAProxy for routing to a Chronos instance. This way you can access a Chronos instance using e.g. `curl loadbalancer:8081`.

`haproxy.cfg`:

```
listen chronos_8081
  bind 0.0.0.0:8081
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option  allbackups
  option http-no-delay
  server chronos01 server_node_1:4400
  server chronos02 server_node_2:4400
  server chronos03 server_node_3:4400
```

Or even better, start Chronos via Marathon, which will ensure given number of instances. Then HAProxy configuration could be generated by:

- [marathon-lb](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb)
- [bamboo](https://github.com/QubitProducts/bamboo)

Comment: I've gone through the HAProxy configuration generated by bamboo. As you should starting Chronos with Marathon should be a better option